# Independence Probability Proof

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I need to prove this question, but I am not sure how to start,
could you help please:

given that $A$ is an even in sample space  $\Omega$ and $B_1, B_2,\dots, B_n$ disjoint events such that,

$B_1 \cup B_2 \cup B_3 \cup \dots \cup B_n = \Omega$

prove that :

$\min(P(A|B_i) \leq P(A) \leq \max(P(A|B_i)$

Comment: I think you mean to say that the $B_i$ are _disjoint_, not independent.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$P(A) = P(A \mid B_1) P(B_1) + \cdots + P(A \mid B_n) P(B_n)$$
and $P(B_1) + \cdots + P(B_n) = 1$. Bound each $P(A \mid B_i)$ by the max and min in the problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

Total law of probability:

$$\mathbb{P}(A)=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}(A|B_i)\mathbb{P}(B_i)\leq \max_i\{\mathbb{P}(A|B_i)\}\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb{P}(B_i)=\max_i\{\mathbb{P}(A|B_i)\}$$

You can similarly deal with the other inequality